# анимация растущей линии на Canvas

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

Подскажите, как реализовать эффект постепенно растущей линии на canvas. Вот простой пример на canvas

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('cnvs');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(70, 80);
ctx.lineTo(150, 10);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
ctx.lineTo(10, 150);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
#cnvs {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cnvs" width="300" height="210">
```

Как сделать, что б в процессе анимации от точки к точке прорисовывался бы путь ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все посчитано при помощи обычной линейной интерполяции, хотя для этого можно было бы использовать `svg.getPointAtLength()`.

Сперва нужно посчитать расстояния между точками и общую длину пути.

Затем, внутри цикла отрисовки необходимо считать сколько времени прошло и в какой точке пути должен находиться растущий конец линии.

Для дополнительной информации читайте комментарии в коде.

```js
let points = [[50,50],[70,80],[150,10],[200,100],[10,150]];
let goal = 10000; // 10 сек

// считаем расстояния между точками
points.forEach((pt, i, arr) => {
    let index = i ? i-1 : arr.length-1;
    let x = arr[index][0] - pt[0];
    let y = arr[index][1] - pt[1];
    pt[2] = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
})

// общая длина пути
let total = points.reduce((acc, el) => el[2] + acc, 0)

// функция линейной интерполяции между точками p1 и p2
let lerp = (t, p1, p2) => [p1[0] + (p2[0] - p1[0])*t, p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1])*t]

let ctx = cnvs.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1])

  // если время конца анимации еще не настало
  if (t < goal) { 
    requestAnimationFrame(draw) // запрашиваем следующий кадр
    growPath(t/goal*total); // рисуем ползущую линию
  } 
  // если анимация закончилась
  else {
    // рисуем замкнутую линию через все точки
    points.forEach((pt, i) => i && ctx.lineTo(pt[0], pt[1]))
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillText((t/goal).toFixed(2), 5, 10)
}

function growPath(t) {
  // длина пути между уже пройденными точками
  let pathLen = 0; 
  for (var i=1; i<=points.length; i++) {
    let pt = points[i] || points[0];
    // если точка уже пройдена
    if (t - pathLen > pt[2]) { 
      pathLen += pt[2]; // считаем пройденный путь
      ctx.lineTo(pt[0], pt[1]); // рисуем полную линию
    } 
    // если точка еще не достигнута 
    else {
      // считаем конечную точку и выходим из цикла
      return ctx.lineTo(...lerp((t-pathLen)/pt[2], points[i-1], pt));
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#cnvs {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cnvs" width="300" height="170"></canvas>
```